# ClipBoard.SetText throws exception when application is running under lock screen Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm building a Windows Phone application which will allow the user to set text remotely even when the application is running under lockscreen.

When I called `ClipBoard.SetText("some data")` when the application was under lock screen, it threw the following exception:

```
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Clipboard_SetText(String text)
at System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(String text)
...
```

Any suggestion or workaround for this issue?

Comment: Is your code running in a background service? Or do you keep your app running using the Idle detection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: It's running under the lock screen using Idle Detection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**According to [msdn]**[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597043%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) The Clipboard.SetText Method is restricted to the usage of a user-initiated action only. Therefore i would not expect .SetText to work in a locked mode.

Well as a App User **this makes sense**. I wouldn't wan't a app messing around with my clipboard while i'm not using the app. Say, I copy a number and by the time i want to paste the number another app replaced the number with another text....

Copied from Remarks:
... These APIs can only be invoked from within a context that is determined by the Silverlight runtime to be in response to a user-initiated action. For example, clipboard access is valid from within a handler for a Click or KeyDown event. For examples of situations that are not considered user-initiated, clipboard access is not valid from a handler for Loaded or from a constructor.

**What about:**
The App persists the text in a temporary store (persisting setting or variable instance) and updates the Clipboard whenever the user returns to the app?